# Etiquette for accepting/declining offer

Tags: job-offer

When someone offers you a job, what’s the etiquette on accepting/declining the offer? Am I obligated to make a decision right then and there, or can I tell them I’ll get back to them, let’s say, in like a day or so?

Answer (score 9):

> Am I obligated to make a decision right then and there, or can I tell
>   them I’ll get back to them, let’s say, in like a day or so?

You should never need to make an on the spot decision.

I always say that I'll need a few days to think it over and discuss it with my family.

And if I'm juggling several offers, I say that I'll need a week or so.

Asking for a week or less has never been a problem during my career.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, they will communicate to you the timeline of making your decision. If not, just ask them how long you have to decide.

Comment: You might want to add that very short timelines are a bad sign, suggesting that the candidate might find the offer much less desirable with research and calm thought.